# Prolog deep version predicate of adding to a list

Tags: prolog, predicate

I have to write a deep version of a predicate that adds a number to each number element in a list and I've done the non-deep version:

```
addnum(N,T,Y)
```

this gives something like:

```
e.g. ?-addnum(7,[n,3,1,g,2],X).
X=[n,10,8,g,9]
```

but I want to create a deep version of addnum now which should do this:

```
e.g. ?-addnumdeep(7,[n,[[3]],q,4,c(5),66],C).
X=[n,[[10]],q,11,c(5),73]
```

Can someone give me some advice? I have started with this:

```
islist([]).
islist([A|B]) :- islist(B).
addnumdeep(C,[],[]).
addnumdeep(C,[Y|Z],[G|M]):-islist(Z),addnum(C,Y,[G,M]),addnumdeep(C,Z,M).
```

but I don't think my logic is right. I was thinking along the lines of checking if the tail is a list then runing addnum on the head and then runnig addnumdeep on the rest of the tail which is a list?

Comment: there might be an `is_list` built in, depending on your platform. just look at the cases that might come up, there are three now at the deepest recusion level, so you might need a new `add` predicate (i'm referring to your previous question).

Comment: If you have `[Y|Z]` you don't need to check if `Z` is a list since it necessarily is already since `[Y|Z]` is a list with tail list `Z`. You need to be checking if `Y` is a list, since it may or may not be. If it is, then `[Y|Z]` is a list containing the list `Y` as its first element.

Comment: @lurker Actually, and as a side remark, the notation `[Head|Tail]` doesn't necessarily imply that `Tail` is a list. For example, `[Y|Z] = [a|b]` is true (with bindings `Y = a, Z = b`).

Comment: check if Y is a list, if so, call `addnumdeep` if not, call `add_if_number`.

Comment: @PauloMoura yes, thanks for pointing that out. I've played with non-list tails in Prolog before. I was a little sloppy in my comment as I had that in the back of my mind when I wrote the comment. In this context, I think it's safe to assume that it's intended/expected to be a list tail. Even so, it's not clear that an explicit check that the tail is indeed a list is necessary here.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could 'catch' the list in first place, adding as *first* clause

```
addnum(N,[T|Ts],[Y|Ys]) :- addnum(N,T,Y),addnum(N,Ts,Ys).
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one solution. The cut is necessary, or else it would backtrack and give false solutions later on. I had tried to use the old `addnum` predicate, but you can't know if you have to go deeper afterwards, so it would only be feasible if you have a `addnum_3levels_deep` predicate and even then it would be clearer to use this solution and count the depth.

```
addnumdeep(N,[X|Y],[G|H]):-
  !, % cut if it is a nonempty list 
  (number(X)->
   G is N + X;
  addnumdeep(N,X,G)), % recurse into head
  addnumdeep(N,Y,H).  % recurse into tail

addnumdeep(_,A,A).
```

Note that this also allows `addnumdeep(7,3,3)`. if you want it to be `addnumdeep(7.3.10)`, you'll have to extract the condition in the brackets:

```
addnumdeep(N,[X|Y],[G|H]):-
  !, % cut if it is a nonempty list
  addnumdeep(N,X,G),
  addnumdeep(N,Y,H).

addnumdeep(N,X,Y):-
  number(X),!, % cut if it is a number.
  Y is N+X.

addnumdeep(_,A,A).
```

This solution is nicer, because it highlights the three basic cases you might encounter:
It is either a list, then recourse, or a number, for everything else, just put it into the result list's tail (this also handles the empty list case). On the other hand you'll need red cuts for this solution, so it might be frowned upon by some purists.

If you don't want red cuts, you can replace the last clause with

`addnumdeep(_,A,A):- !, \+ number(A), \+ A = [_|_].`

If you don't want non-lists to be allowed, you could check with `is_list` if it is a list first and then call the proposed predicate.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with something that tells me whether a term is list-like or not, something along these lines:

```
is_list_like( X     ) :- var(X) , ! , fail .
is_list_like( []    ) .
is_list_like( [_|_] ) .
```

Then it's just adding another case to your existing predicate, something like this:

```
add_num( _ , [] , [] ) .          % empty list? all done!
add_num( N , [X|Xs] , [Y|Ys] ) :- % otherwise...
  number(X) ,                     % - X is numeric?
  Y is X + N ,                    % - increment X and add to result list
  add_num( N , Xs , Ys )          % - recurse down
  .                               %
add_num( N , [X|Xs] , [Y|Ys] ) :- % otherwise...
  is_list_like( X ) ,             % - X seems to be a list?
  ! ,
  add_num( N , X , Y ) ,          % - recurse down on the sublist
  add_num( N , Xs , Ys )          % - then recurse down on the remainder
  .                               %
add_num( N , [X|XS] , [Y|Ys] ) :- % otherwise (X is unbound, non-numeric and non-listlike
  X = Y ,                         % - add to result list
  add_num( N , Xs , Ys )          % - recurse down
  .                               %
```